# WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database to the newest version

Tags: database, admin

whenever I attempt to access our production admin panel I get the message below.

"Database Update Required
WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database to the newest version.
The database update process may take a little while, so please be patient.
Update WordPress Database"

I have not seen this before, does anyone know why this appeared? Our site was down previously and my concern is, if this update will bring the site down again. I want to make sure that this update will not bring our site down again and have seen post of other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common message where the WP update also requires to make changes to the database.

The answer if this will cause problems or not is hard to give, but the solution is to test this on a staging or local development version of your site, which is not valuable.

Or, to make sure you have a very recent backup which you can easily revert to, in case you can only make this update on the production version.